# Can we plot a FFT for a Decibel vs Seconds data?

Tags: acoustics, computational-physics, fourier-transform, software, data-analysis

I was plotting FFT for Decibel values corresponding to the time in which it was recorded using a DAQ for My project, The sample data looks like this,

I was attempting to plot the FFT thinking that the time and the decibel values are going to plot but what came out was nothing short of noise,
Can anyone advice regarding the data and how we have to filter so that we are able to get a meaningful FFT.

I am a bit naive when it comes to signals as I am not a Electronics engineer, Please Help anyone.

My matlab code is very simple that is 
$$data=[values,values...]$$
$$seconds=[time1,time2,...]$$
$$x=fft(data)$$
$$plot(x)$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that Matlab's FFT function returns complex numbers. What you get in that plot is the real part on the x-axis, and the imaginary part on the y-axis. What you probably want to do is to plot(frequency, power). The power is abs(x).^2 (that you then need to transform into dB), and you need to calculate the frequency from the sampling rate in the data and the number of data points.

Comment: *Signal Processing SE* might be more suitable for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Anders Sandberg mentioned in his comment, the Fourier transform (fft function in MATLAB) returns a vector of complex numbers. When you try to plot that, you will end up with its representation on the complex plane, where the x-axis is the real part and the y-axis is the imaginary part.

If you would like to plot that as magnitude against frequency you would have to use the function abs() to get the magnitude of the spectrum. Additionally, as Anders Sandberg also mentions, you could square that to get the power of the signal.

Now, one more thing to note is that when the input to the Fourier transform routine (the fft function that is, but this is true for the Fourier transform in general) is real you will end up with a vector of numbers which will be symmetric (in MATLAB's case) in respect to its middle element. In order to assess the frequency content of the signal, the first half is adequate (keep in mind that you need the full vector for the inverse Fourier transform).

A sample code that could achieve that could look like this

```
x = load('data.mat'); % Import the data -> use whatever method you use
t = load('time.mat'); % Import the time vector -> use whatever method you use

y = fft(x); % Fourier transform the data
yDB = 10 * log10(abs(y)); % Convert to dB -> use 10 * log10(abs(y).^2) if you want to get the power
Ts = t(2) - t(1); % Find the sampling period
fs = 1/Ts; % Sampling frequency
f = linspace(0, fs/2, length(x)/2); % Calculate the frequency axis

% Plot the result
figure(1)
semilogx(f, yDB(1:end/2)) % You can use plot() instead of semilogx if you want to plot on linear frequency axis
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)', 'FontSize', 16)
ylabel('Amplitude (dB)', 'FontSize', 16)
grid on
```